# Unexpected token, expected "..." in ChannelSearch.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error

I am making a small project but when I typed `value {query}` and `onChange {onSearch}` it gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: D:\no\client\src\components\ChannelSearch.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "..." (17:16)      

  15 |          </div>
  16 |          <input className='channel-search+__input__text' placeholder='Search perhaps?' type='text' 
> 17 |          value={query}
     |                 ^
  18 |
  19 |          onChange {onSearch} />
  20 |         </div>
```

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are the `=` ?

Comment: `value={query}` doesn't work?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this:

```
</div>
  <input className='channel-search+__input__text' placeholder='Search perhaps?' type='text' 
         value={query}
          onChange={onSearch} />
          </div>
```

Comment: This surprisingly worked for me, I just add another div without a className in, Thank you so much!